# Firebase Storage isn't a function, in vuejs app

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

Good day developers, I'm building this app in Vuejs with Firebase, storing some videos and images in my Storage module of Firebase, but then when I initialize the function of retrieving that images I got this error: "firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.storage(...).ref(...).child(...).then is not a function"

On my Vuex method, I set this in order to access the image in my firebase storage

```js
actions: {
    getVideoAboutMe({commit}) {
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref("myVideo")
        .child("coverr-a-greek-cemetery-top-view-1578925848736.mp4")
        .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
          commit("setVideoAboutMe", uploadTaskSnapshot);
          console.log(uploadTaskSnapshot);
          return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        })

        .catch((error) => {
          alert("Error", error);

        });
    },
```

And my main js file is designed on this way:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/storage";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.component("myAboutMe", aboutTag);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  created() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    });
    this.$store.dispatch("getVideoAboutMe");
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

then all the logic on components is created, but the error refers exactly to this method in the vuex , like if storage didn't exist(i assume it does cause of importing the firebase).
Any advice about how could I improve this?...thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#child) doesn't return a promise, so you can't call `then()` on it.  It returns a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) object.  If you want to get the download URL for the object referred to by that reference, just call [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl) on it directly.  It returns a promise.

```
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref("myVideo")
        .child("coverr-a-greek-cemetery-top-view-1578925848736.mp4")
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(...)
        .catch(...)
```

Comment: Really Thanks Douglas